# I uninstalled all python versions but when I type python it’s still there. How to fix it?

Tags: python, windows, uninstallation

I uninstalled all my versions of python and made sure that they are not showing up in Control Panel. Then I went to cmd and typed python and in a magic way, python 3.7.7 showed up. How am I supposed to uninstall it?

OS: WINDOWS 10 PRO

Answer (score 2):

Go to windows command prompt and type:

```
where python
```

Should give you the path to the location of the binary excutable.

In the prompt you can also use

```
py --list-paths
```

You could also start python and execute this script

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
```

Also after uninstalling try to restart. (Besides I don't believe this will solve it).

After located try to follow the steps provided by aditya: [here](https://superuser.com/a/1301610/1017302)

> 1. Go to C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs
> 2. Delete Python
> 3. Folder Go to Control Panel >> **Uninstall a Program**
> 4. Right Click on Python and then **Change/Modify**
> 5. Click on **Repair** Python. **Note: This may or may not fail, but be patient**
> 6. Now Again go to step 3
> 7. Now, after step 3, uninstall Python

Quote of above link, work of [Aditya Borka](https://superuser.com/users/880304/aditya-borkar)

Comment: Thank you so much! It somehow automatically installed through Microsoft Store.

Comment: You welcome consider accepting the answer (green arrow) if it solved your problem :) as other might abel to profit of it

Comment: This doesn't really explain how to remove it

Comment: Did you see / read the provided reference?